# Debugger/watcher - like object explorer in IntelliJ IDEA plugins

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to use the interface that IDEA's debugger or variable watcher use for browsing through objects and its fields. Users are familiar with its usage and it would provide better UX. Is it possible to use it in our own custom plugins ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [XInspectDialog](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/02c2d3db68a880a0c3c6606e363072907c2fdd67/platform/xdebugger-impl/src/com/intellij/xdebugger/impl/ui/tree/XInspectDialog.java#L41-L41), though it is in xdebugger-impl, not public API.